# Avoiding "double search" when using regexp matching groups

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Is there a more efficient way of doing this:

```
if re.search("(?P<value>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*) (?P<units>KB|MB|GB|TB|PB)", line):
    m = re.search("(?P<value>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*) (?P<units>KB|MB|GB|TB|PB)", line)
    self.capacity = convert_to_bytes(m.group("units"), m.group("value"))
```

Like in C and other languages you can do this and avoid executing the search twice:

```
if m = re.search("(?P<value>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*) (?P<units>KB|MB|GB|TB|PB)", line):
    self.capacity = convert_to_bytes(m.group("units"), m.group("value"))
```

Is this a better way of doing this?

```
m = re.search("(?P<value>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*) (?P<units>KB|MB|GB|TB|PB)", line)

if m:
    self.capacity = convert_to_bytes(m.group("units"), m.group("value"))
```

Comment: Your last code block is exactly how you're supposed to do it in Python. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

As @Christian Aichinger says, this is correct way, but I'd trim the regex a bit:

```
m = re.search("(?i)(?P<value>[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?) (?P<units>KB|MB|GB|TB|PB)", line)
if m:
    self.capacity = convert_to_bytes(m.group("units"), m.group("value"))
```

Now, `[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?` will match some digit(s) and optionally decimal fractions after it. Mind that in case you have other decimal separator, or if you want to include a thousand digit grouping symbol(s), you'd rather use a character class like `[0-9]+(?:[., ][0-9]+)?` (in Russian or Polish, a space is a valid thousand digit grouping symbol).

Also, making the regex pattern case-insensitive is also a good idea, so that it also matched `1,000 kb`.

[Sample code](https://ideone.com/JAD60g):

```
import re
line = "1.56 kb"
m = re.search("(?i)(?P<value>[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?) (?P<units>KB|MB|GB|TB|PB)", line)
if m:
    print m.group("units") + " - " + m.group("value")
```

Output:

```
kb - 1.56
```